# Facebook graph login API reports "Error validating verification code" with matching redirect uri's

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk

"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

My app with fb login works great in my localhost env, but fails with the above on a live domain name flow.

- facebook/graph-sdk 5.3.1   Facebook SDK for PHP

With the above sdk, login helper getLoginUrl() returns the following (decoded)

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=###...&state=#a#b#c...&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.3.1&redirect_uri=https://my.live.domain.net/&scope=email
```

And Client OAuth Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs contains precicely

```
https://my.live.domain.net/
```

Has anyone else cleared this hurdle?